# IDbConnection with MySql in .Net Core - can't inject with autofac

Tags: mysql, .net-core, autofac

Using autofac I'm trying to Register IDbConnection with MySQL connection string

```
 builder
     .Register<IDbConnection>(c => new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
     .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

And my _connectionString is:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "server=127.0.0.1;user id=mysqltest;password=test;port=3306;database=blog;"
}
```

Unfortunately I have an error: `System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'port'.'`

With MS SQL (which has no port) everything works fine. 
The problem is with MySQL only.

I've installed: `MySql.Data`and `MySqlConnector`. Do I need anything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `SqlConnection` is meant for Sql Server, not for mysql.

You need to register an instance of `MySqlConnection`

```
builder
    .Register<IDbConnection>(c => new MySqlConnection(_connectionString))
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Comment: Thanks, furthermore it seems that `MySql.Data` package is enough. No need to have `MySqlConnector`